# Captcha mage doesn't change after click YII1

Tags: php, yii, captcha

I need change captcha image when I click on it, the captcha with form located in CJuiDialog.Also form loaded via ajax In view I set:

```
 <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha', array('clickableImage' => true,'showRefreshButton'=>false,'captchaAction'=>'/site/captcha')); ?>
```

But when I click on an image it not change.Tell me please what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add  id in widget:

```
   <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha', array('id'=>'captahca_id','clickableImage' => true,'showRefreshButton'=>false,'captchaAction'=>'captcha')); ?>
```